# Node Js - TransactionError with mssql (ENOTBEGUN)

Tags: javascript, node.js, transactions

**Node Js (v7.10.0) + mssql (3.3.0)**

I want execute three statements in a transaction but when I try to commit, it return a error: TransactionError: Transaction has not begun. Call begin() first.

```
       var conn = new sql.Connection(dbConfig);
       conn.connect().then(function() {
          test();
       }).catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
       });        

    function test() {
       var mssqlTransaction = new sql.Transaction(conn);
        mssqlTransaction.begin(function(err) {
             var sqlInsert = "My Insert";
             var request1 = new sql.Request(mssqlTransaction);
             request1.query(sqlInsert, function(err, recordset) {
                if (err != undefined && err.length == 0) {
                    erros.push(err);
                }                   
             });

             var sqlDelete = "My Delete";
             var request2 = new sql.Request(mssqlTransaction);
             request2.query(sqlDelete , function(err, recordset) {
                if (err != undefined && err.length == 0) {
                    erros.push(err);
                }                   
             });

             var sqlUpdate = "My Update";
             var request3 = new sql.Request(mssqlTransaction);
             request3.query(sqlUpdate , function(err, recordset) {
                if (err != undefined && err.length == 0) {
                    erros.push(err);
                }                   
             });

             mssqlTransaction.commit(function(err) {
                 console.log('Error in commit:'+err);
             });
        });
    }
```

Comment: My js isn't that great, but don't you need a mssqltransaction.connect() line? Also you have some spaces in your code (ex: request1 .query) that  will need corrected as well.

Comment: Really, I just made a part of the code to exemplify my mistake. Now I edit the code.

Answer (score 0):

This should be comment but I don't have enough reputation.

Your request1 statement doesn't wait for the transaction to begin and goes on to execute the transaction so to wait for the transaction to start use

```
await new Promise(resolve => mssqlTransaction.begin(resolve));
```

And to commit the transaction too you can may like to use

```
await new Promise(resolve => mssqlTransaction.commit(resolve));
```

Try to use **async** and **await** because entire thing is asynchronous.